# Convert encoded array to jquery with embd CRS as a Object using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, multidimensional-array

`let images =  ["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg"]`

**Convert this Encoded Array to this using JQuery.....**
I have images encoded array, I want to add src: images like I mention down in the items collection.

````
          {
            src: '1.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '2.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '3.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '4.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '5.jpg'
          }
        ],```
````

Comment: ok, what have you tried? Sounds like you want to look into https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: items: [
          {
            src: '1jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '2.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '3.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '4.jpg'
          },
        ],

Comment: thats your desired result, which you said you need to use jQuery to get to. Have you tried something?

Comment: I am Laravel Developer, Intermediate in jquery So plz tell me the proper way how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
var data= images.map(obj=> ({"src" : obj}));
```

output

```
[
  {
    "src": "1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "src": "2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "src": "3.jpg"
  },
  {
    "src": "4.jpg"
  },
  {
    "src": "5.jpg"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the jQuery equivalent

```js
let images = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg"];
let obj = {
  items: $.map(images, function(o) {
    return {
      src: o
    }
  })
}
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```